# Declare function with memory address

Tags: c++, c++14, memory-address

I'm trying to call a function through its memory address.

I've done something like:

```
int GetNewValue(int args)
{
  return args * 2;
}

int main()
{
  /*
      Function address: 0x22feac
  */

  int(*GetVal)(int) = 0x22feac; // instead of '&GetNewValue'
}
```

But at compile time, i get the following error:

> [Error] invalid conversion from `int` to `int (*)(int)` [`-fpermissive`]

How can I call a method from its address?

(Note the above example uses a constant for simplicity, but in my real code I am hooking a function from a DLL injection.)

Comment: you can use `reinterpret_cast`, but why you doing this?

Comment: You can perform casting games on that int, but why? C++'s typing rules are designed to prevent this sort of stuff.

Comment: You wanna get this to compile? Change it to `int(*GetVal)(int) = (int(*)(int))0x22feac;`. But then this is UD, are you sure you want it?

Comment: @appleapple, user45813101 because i want hook a function form a dll injection.

Comment: @DeiDei worked! i did not know correct syntax, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address `0x22feac` looks like any address in normal code address space. But this depends on your environment. It is generally a bad idea to use an address specified by a number literal in your source code.

But there might be an address that you got from outside, such as from the Windows function [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx). If you are sure you really know what you are doing, then you can assign such a value to a function pointer:

```
intptr_t functionAddress = 0x22feac;
auto GetVal = reinterpret_cast<int(*)(int)>(functionAddress);
```

The `auto` allows you to follow the "Don't repeat yourself" pattern.